# Access contract by address, without knowing implementation

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, web3js, contract-deployment

I want to access and interact with a deployed contract. My restriction: Knowing the API (functions, fields), but not the implementation.

I was looking at the Ethereum documentation "Accessing Contracts and Transactions" (http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/contracts-and-transactions/accessing-contracts-and-transactions.html).

They have this Web3.js

```
var source = 'contract Multiply7 { event Print(uint); function multiply(uint input) returns (uint) { Print(input * 7); return input * 7; } }';
var compiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(source);
var Multiply7 = web3.eth.contract(compiled.Multiply7.info.abiDefinition);
var multi = Multiply7.at("0x0ab60714033847ad7f0677cc7514db48313976e2")
multi.multiply.sendTransaction(6, {from: "0xeb85a5557e5bdc18ee1934a89d8bb402398ee26a"})
```

However, this requires to know the implementation of the contract, which does not make sense to me.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is the address of the contract and the JSON representation of the Application Binary Interface.

To get the ABI:

```
> var source = 'contract Multiply7 { event Print(uint); function multiply(uint input) returns (uint) { Print(input * 7); return input * 7; } }';
undefined
> var compiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(source);
undefined
> compiled.Multiply7.info.abiDefinition
[{
    constant: false,
    inputs: [{
        name: "input",
        type: "uint256"
    }],
    name: "multiply",
    outputs: [{
        name: "",
        type: "uint256"
    }],
    payable: false,
    type: "function"
}, {
    anonymous: false,
    inputs: [{
        indexed: false,
        name: "",
        type: "uint256"
    }],
    name: "Print",
    type: "event"
}]
```

So, without knowing the implementation but only the address and the ABI, you should be able to execute the following command:

```
var Multiply7 = web3.eth.contract([{constant: false, inputs: [{name: "input", type: "uint256"}], name: "multiply", outputs: [{name: "", type: "uint256"}], payable: false, type: "function"}, {anonymous: false, inputs: [{indexed: false, name: "", type: "uint256"}], name: "Print", type: "event"}]);
var multi = Multiply7.at("0x0ab60714033847ad7f0677cc7514db48313976e2")
multi.multiply.sendTransaction(6, {from: "0xeb85a5557e5bdc18ee1934a89d8bb402398ee26a"})
```